# cpanel: solve ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, a-records

I'm using cpanel the first time and I got the following error: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Is here someone, who can help me to fix that issue? Here you can find the complete log of errors: https://intodns.com/kickbox.org

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you Please Brief About it...

Have you taken a Shared Hosting Plan or you have taken a VPS or a Decicated Server...

As if you have taken a shared Hosting Plan then Owner use to Provide their Name Servers to setup in your Domain.

And in case of VPS/Dedicated Server, you have to create it via WHM > Basic Configuration and you also need to create Child Name Server in Domain control with the IP of your VPS/Dedicated Server...

Hope this will Help you..